# how to get the datepicker class value in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a dynamic datepicker field so I have a `datepicker` class for that in which I need to get the value of `datepicker`. I have tried with `id` in which I have got the value of the `datepicker`

using `id`

```
$("#datepicker").change(function() {
    selectedate= $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
    console.log(selectedate);
});
```

I have tried the same thing with `class` but I cannot get the value of datepicker

```
$(".datepicker").change(function() {
    selectedate= $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).text();
    console.log(selectedate);
});
```

Comment: Use `$(this)`. `$(this).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples.

```
$(".datepicker").change(function() {
    var selectedate = $(this).val();
    console.log(selectedate);
});
```

`this` refers to the DatePicker itself within the `change` function parameter.

EDIT: Just seen you've had some issue between using `'#datepicker'` or `'.datepicker'`. Please post your HTML for the datepicker for help with this, as well as providing further information if the solution provided doesn't work.

N.B., for HTML-JS questions, try using [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It'll help get answers to your questions very quickly, and maybe identify other issues in the code for you, e.g., suggesting better practices is something people do for me a lot when I post code to there, which helps me become a better programmer.

Comment: Awesome! Accept the answer by clicking the tick below the vote counters if this worked for you :) Also note the NB comments for future questions - you've asked it just fine, but this will help increase response rates for more difficult problems.

Comment: i have to wait for 5 min

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `val()` not `text()`.